# Plotting the mean difference of two different sample sizes, with the effect size in R

Tags: regression, r, permutation-test

I have a simple data frame of approximately 1750 participants. But have taken the first 11 participants to form the example. From the `all_groups` variable, I have 4 different sized groups.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
                 LIPA = c(1654.128, 2179.699, 2611.728, 1372.5936, 
    770.6160, 90.0144, 1830.2256, 1960.0560, 2480.7888, 1649.1888, 
    3040.3296), all_groups = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3',
     '2', '4', '4'))
```

I am interested in creating a plot which can visualise the processed data, the mean differences between the groups as well as the effect size. Ideally this would be achieved with a Cummings estimation plot or a Gardner-Altman plot from this data. To do this, I am wanting to use the package `dabestr`.

So far I have created a linear model with added 95% confidence intervals for estimated mean of the LIPA variable and each group, and loaded the data into the appropriate format.

```r
LIPA_mod1 <- lm(LIPA ~ all_groups, data = data)
LIPA_pred_data <- data.frame(all_groups = c('1','2','3','4'))
LIPA_pred_data <- cbind(LIPA_pred_data, predict(LIPA_mod1, 
                   newdata = LIPA_pred_data, interval = 'confidence'))
colnames(LIPA_pred_data)[2] <- 'LIPA'

two_groups_unpaired <- load(df,
                            x = all_groups, y = LIPA,
                            idx = list(c("1", "2", "3")))
```

However, when attempting to obtain the mean differences by running

```r
two_groups_unpaired.mean_diff <- mean_diff(two_groups_unpaired)
```

I am met with the following error:

```r
Error in PermutationTest(ctrl_measurement, test_measurement,   
  effect_size = effect_size_type,  : 
  The two arrays do not have the same length.
```

I understand this is because my samples do not have the same number of participants in them, but am wondering whether there is a way around this from a visualisation perspective? Although the different sample sizes will have differing effects, unless I am mistaken, should it not be possible to account for these and still plot them?

Comment: You need to have equal group sizes for a permutation test. You could randomly remove some until group sizes are equal, or choose a different test.

Comment: Appears that you need more statistical theory before you will be ready for programming.

Comment: @rw2 It's not true that a permutation test requires that the groups have equal sizes: the OP has unpaired data which we can infer from "two_groups_unpaired". The problem is that the OP is using a non-standard function `mean_diff` but they don't have a minimally reproducible example, so it's not clear where that function is coming from.